# Xcode 6 flushing NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, settings, nsuserdefaults

my application stores some state information inside NSUserDefaults. When using Build & Run with the newest version of Xcode 6 (the GM), all the defaults are flushed upon install. In addition, values entered in my Settings.bundle are removed (which is another sign of the user defaults being flushed). Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears I was a little mislead. I checked for some files being present in the apps document directory on startup. If they were not, I removed stuff from the NSUserDefaults. Apple seems to have updated the Xcode Build&Run implementation leading to a new app file path (the identifier inside the path changes) each time Build&Run is executed. When simply restarting the app in a normal way without Build&Run (so as a normal user would do), everything is working fine and the path stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use below. It will work now.

```
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group identifier"]; // this is introduced in iOS8
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"test"];
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] synchronize];
```

If it still doesn't work, make `Product>>Clean`

Comment: that is obviously not working since you are always allocating a new instance of NSUserDefaults. In addition I need to be able to use the standardDefaults in order to keep my Settings.bundle working.

Comment: @TimSpecht : did you find solution then? I believe its always allocating bcz of this line `[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group identifier"];`. Check if nsuserdefault group is present or not. if not, then use this line...

Comment: I actually found the cause of the problem: The path for the documents directory changes evey time  I start the app :(

Comment: @TimSpecht : please post the answer if you find the solution... I am going to upgrade all apps from next week onwards